# Procedure for Self Registering of Class

Tags: c++

I have some self-registering header files.

```
Registration<ClassName> objVar ("ClassName ");
```

I am adding this Registration call in the `.h` file itself.
I am referring from (http://derydoca.com/2019/03/c-tutorial-auto-registering-factory/)

Now when I am including this `.h` file from different `.cpp` files, in an Project, it is complaining that  **Registration already been defined in some different .obj file.**

Could you help me with the right process on how to handle this (below are some of the options I find)?

1. I thought like including that Registration in `.cpp`, but then we
   have to include those `.cpp` to all projects where I need registering.
2. Or I can use `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` as part of Linker Properties.

Comment: Seems like an oversight or typo in the blog post. The registration must be in the `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to define global variables (`objVar` in this case) in a header file. If the header file is included from more than one compilation unit (.cpp file), you will get more than one `objVar` and the linker will complain.

Since `objVar` is only used as a trick to call the `Registration<ClassName>` constructor before the `main()` function, the name and scope of `objVar` is unimportant. You can declare it as static or inside an anonymous namespace in a .cpp file. I suppose you could declare it as static in a header file as well, but then the constructor would be called more than once (since there will be one copy of `objVar` per object file), but it seems like that would be ok with this implementation of `registerGenerator`.

Not exactly sure what `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` does, but it is possible it will also run the constructor more than once. It seems like an ugly solution though, and not portable.

If you want the constructor to be called only once, you should put the `Registration<>` definitions in a .cpp file and link with it. Or just initialize everything the traditional way, i.e. from `main()`.